# Inner div 100% height not working inside a div with min-height

Tags: html, css, layout

I have div (`#child`) which won't expand to the full height of it's parent (`#parent`). I've set the height for both `html` and `body`. It works if I set the parent's height as 100%, but I want the parent to have a minimum height, and the child to expand to the parent's full height.

HTML:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="parent">
          <div id="child">
              <p>This area should be have the same height as it's parent.</p>
           </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
html, body, header, h1, p { margin: 0; padding: 0; }

html         { background-color: #DDD; height: 100%; }
body         { background-color: #DAA; height: 100%; }

#parent {
  min-height: 70%;
  height: auto !important;
  height: 70%;

  background-color: #AAD;
}

#child {
  height: 100%; /* why isn't this working ? */

  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;    
  background-color: #ADA;
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nxVNX/11/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
height: auto !important;
```

Don't ever use `!important`, because it cannot be overriden, work with it is harmfull.
It didn't work because it always used `height: auto;` not `height: 70%;`

> A rule that has the !important property will always be applied no
>   matter where that rule appears in the CSS document.

So i recommend to you remove this line and it will works.

Have look for more information about [What does !important mean in CSS?](http://webdesign.about.com/od/css/f/blcssfaqimportn.htm).

Comment: I picked up the min-height snippet from here: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/cross-browser-min-height/ and assumed it's best practice. Didn't even try to fiddle with that bit. I'll be less gulible from now on :))

Answer (score 2):

It works when you remove the `!important;` property. Maybe that's the problem?
I tried several other methods, but they didn't work, so the solution above could be the only one, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Am not sure why this is not working , but this will work

```
#parent {
  min-height: 70%;
  height: 100% !important;
  height: 100%;  
  background-color: #AAD;
}
```